# PowerShell - get process ID of called application

Tags: powershell, process

I need to call an external application (i.e. & 'Notepad' )
and then get the process ID of the called application.

Get-Process Notepad  = will return all Notepad processes

I want to do something like:

```
$objApp = & 'c:\Notepad.exe'

WHILE (get-process -ID $objApp.id | select -property Responding) {
  Start-Sleep -s 10
  Echo "STILL WAITING"
}
Echo "Done!!"
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` with the `-PassThru` argument like  this:

```
$app = Start-Process notepad -passthru
Wait-Process $app.Id
```

Comment: @JohnDemetriou It tells Start-Process to output the process object  onto the pipeline (i.e. "to pass it thru the pipeline")

Answer (score 14):

More succinct:

```
# Starts Notepad and returns the ID
(Start-Process Notepad -passthru).ID
```