# kill remote job initiated by invoke-command

Tags: windows, powershell, kill-process, invoke-command

what is the easy way to kill remote job initiated by invoke-command with background processes?

I kick remote PS script to run legacy exe file and need a way to kill that process.

I was going to use stop-job first but as I am reading it works only for local processes.

Then I was going to use Remove-job -force command but if I understood right, it cannot kill running process until it completes (again my remote ps script will start another process to run exe file).

I am reading I can kill a process using wmi terminate command but I do not know how to get PID of remote process (I cannot use name because I can kill processes from other users)

what is the best way to achieve my goal?

my script looks like that:

```
invoke-command -computername server1,server2,server3..etc -script-block {my.exe} -asjob

loop to wait for all processes to complete and report progress

   check for CTRL-C press and kill all remote instances on {my.exe}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok checked this morning from work and this works fine from a calling script:

```
get-job | remove-job -force
```

I was confused by MSDN doc which says:

```
When you stop a background job, Windows PowerShell **completes** all tasks that are pending in that job queue and then ends the job
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer, you can add the start process command to your script block and return the pid or save it to a text file to be reference later.

[PowerShell - get process ID of called application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762982/powershell-get-process-id-of-called-appication)