# Wait for process to end

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script that will automatically print all .pdf files in a folder with Foxit. I have it set to wait until Foxit has exited until the script continues. Every once in a while, the script will pause and wait even though Foxit has already exited. Is there a way to make it time out after a certain amount of time?

Here is the code I have:

```
Start-Process $foxit -ArgumentList $argument -Wait
Move-Item $filePath $printed[$location]
Add-Content "$printLogDir\$logFileName" $logEntry
```

I've tried the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741490/how-to-tell-powershell-to-wait-for-each-command-to-end-before-starting-the-next) and they don't seem to work. For example if I do:

```
$proc = Start-Process $foxit -ArgumentList $argument
$proc.WaitForExit()
Move-Item $filePath $printed[$location]
Add-Content "$printLogDir\$logFileName" $logEntry
```

I get:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. If I start it with `Invoke-WmiMethod` I can get the process ID and wait for it, then ask it to time out.

```
$proc = Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "$foxit $argument"
Wait-Process -Id $proc.ProcessId -Timeout 120
Move-Item $filePath $printed[$location]
Add-Content "$printLogDir\$logFileName" $logEntry
```

This seems to work pretty consistantly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement a timeout is to use a background job:

```
$Job = start-job -ScriptBlock { write-output 'start';Start-Sleep -Seconds 15 }

$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 10
$timer = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

  While ($timer.Elapsed -le $timeout)
   {
    if ($Job.State -eq 'Completed' )
     {
      Receive-Job $Job
      Remove-Job  $Job
      Return
     } 
     Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    } 
      write-warning 'Job timed out.  Stopping job'
      Stop-Job $Job
      Receive-Job $Job
      Remove-Job  $Job
```

Comment: Using the backgroud job wasn't working for me. I'm not exacty sure why but I think it has to do with the variables not passing on to the job.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem and found a slightly [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762982/powershell-get-process-id-of-called-application) that also captures the output of the child process. The `-PassThru` argument is key as it returns a process object for each process that the cmdlet starts.

```
$proc = Start-Process $foxit -ArgumentList $argument -PassThru
Wait-Process -Id $proc.Id -Timeout 120
Move-Item $filePath $printed[$location]
Add-Content "$printLogDir\$logFileName" $logEntry
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this style to have better control what to do during the runtime of the external process:

```
$waitTime = 60
$dism = Start-Process "$env:windir\system32\dism.exe" -ArgumentList "/Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth" -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden
while (!$dism.HasExited -or $waitTime -gt 0) {sleep -Seconds 1; $waitTime--}
"done."
```

By cheking the HasExited-attribute I can continue with my code with any other tasks in parallel.