# Kill Excel process created in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Given that I write to a workbook, I currently kill all Excel processes so that my code works when I call it in a loop.

```
xlswrite(path,values);
system('taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.EXE');
```

This makes me unable to run the code while I am working in another Excel file. How do I make it so that Matlab terminates only the Excel processes that itself created?

Comment: As of R2019a  [writematrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) or [writecell](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writecell.html) are  recommended functions for writing to excel files.

Comment: @rahnema1 does these not have the same problem? I've been using the similarly named `writetable` for a long time and it believe it leaves a hidden Excel instance open if writing to xlsx...

Comment: @Wolfie Those functions have an option 'UseExcel' that  should be set to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a "feature" introduced somewhere around R2015b to speed up multiple writes to Excel... not very user/memory friendly!

The `xlswrite` documentation links to this [MathWorks Support Answer](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102070-how-do-i-write-data-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-a-custom-cell-background-color-and-custom-font-colo) to manually write to Excel using `actxserver`, you can then manually delete the COM object referencing Excel.

You can actually `edit xlswrite` and see that it uses `matlab.io.internal.getExcelInstance`, which does the same thing and creates a COM interface with `actxserver`.

A cheeky option would be to copy `xlswrite`, add the `Excel` variable it creates as an output, and `Quit` and `delete` it afterwards, as shown below. I don't advocate breaking any of The MathWorks' copyright ownership of that function.

A less cheeky option would be to create a comparable function based on the answer I linked above, for writing data only it would look something like this:

```
function xlswriteClean( File, Data, Range )
% XLSWRITECELAN writes data like XLSWRITE, but deletes the Excel instance! 
%  XLSWRITECELAN (FILE,DATA,RANGE) writes the variable in
%  DATA to FILE, in the range specified by RANGE. 
%  RANGE is optional, defaults to "A1"
    % Obtain the full path name of the file
    % Could handle this more elegantly, i.e. 
    % this always assumes the current directory, but user might give a full path
    file = fullfile(pwd, File);
    % Open an ActiveX connection to Excel
    h = actxserver('excel.application');
    %Create a new work book (excel file)
    wb = h.WorkBooks.Add();
    % Select the appropriate range
    if nargin < 3
        Range = 'A1';
    end
    rng = h.Activesheet.get('Range', Range); 
    % Write the data to the range
    rng.value = Data; 
    % Save the file with the given file name, close Excel
    wb.SaveAs( File );  
    % Clean up - the point of this function
    wb.Close;
    h.Quit;
    h.delete;
end
```

You can customise basically everything within the new Excel workbook using the COM object `h`, so you could add any functionality which you use in `xlswrite` like sheet naming etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can [start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763069/6579744) the excel process by powershell and get its process id then use the process id to kill the process:

```
[~, pid] = system('powershell (Start-Process excel.exe -passthru).Id');
% Do your work
% ...
system(['powershell Stop-Process -Id ' pid])
```