# How to stop a process started by the system function in MATLAB in Windows system?

Tags: matlab, system

I have to use **matlab system function to call external process**, but sometimes **the process might be stuck in running and I want to force the process to shut down after certain time period, and then continue to run the remain codes**. I know Time class could do some help, but such as 'kill/utime' could not be used on Windows system, would anyone mind pointing out suggestions, I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56146305/6579744) may help.

Comment: I am sorry that I'm not familiar with powershell, would you minding showing some simple codes to control the running time of the external process, thanks.

Comment: In the linked post it is explained how to run a program (excel) and kill  it. Simply copy/paste the code. But replace excel.exe with the name of your program. You don't need to be familiar with powershell. In the first line MATLAB uses  powershell to start a program. In the scond lind the program is killed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but in fact, I need to run cmd line to execute ABAQUS python scripts, it is something like "abaqus cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py" in normal cmd.exe or with system call in MATLAB, but I can not just substitute it with 'powershell (Start-Process abaqus cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py -passthru).Id)' in system powershell call in MATLAB. It always show errors with verifying file-path.

Comment: I think you need to use - ArgumentList option. Please see [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7) manual. If it doesn't work I think you need to convert your comment to a new question with powershell tag that how to start abaqus using powershell.

Comment: Try 'powershell (Start-Process abaqus -ArgumentList "cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py" -passthru).Id)'

Comment: Thanks, it did work. By the way, I needed a little modification as 'powershell (Start-Process abaqus -ArgumentList "cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py  ask_delete=OFF" -passthru).Id)'. This line worked well in powershell, but in MATLAB system call, it could not identify the space between '.py' and 'ask_delte...' and show 'the positional form parameter that accepts the actual parameter "ask_delete=OFF" could not be found'.

Comment: Both of these should work: `[~, pid] = system('powershell (Start-Process abaqus -ArgumentList ''cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py ask_delete=OFF'' -passthru).Id');` and `[~, pid] = system('powershell (Start-Process abaqus -ArgumentList \"cae noGUI=xxx.cae/xxx.py ask_delete=OFF\" -passthru).Id');`