# Process ID is not found in the task manager processes after Start-Process using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, browser, taskmanager, start-process

I tried to open a new incognito chrome window and want to close it.

```
$URL = 'www.google.com'
$appInstance = Start-Process -FilePath Chrome -passthru -ArgumentList @( '-incognito', $URL, '--new-window')
Write-Host "App ID : " $appInstance.Id
Stop-Process -ID 3716 -Force
```

**Output**

```
App ID :  3716
```

**Error**

```
Stop-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 3716.
```

My requirement is if I run the script 5 times then 5 chrome instances are open.  Now it should close a specific window depending upon its Process ID.

Can it be possible to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell - get process ID of called application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762982/powershell-get-process-id-of-called-application)

Comment: updated question. Can you help?

Comment: `taskkill` would be better for this imo. Try `taskkill /f /t /pid 3716`

Comment: I don't think it will work. Reason being the process id i am getting after start the process is not present in the task manager.

Comment: Chrome runs multiple child instances -- `'--new-window'` could mean your pid simply appends an existing processs, then ends immediately because it's done -- which is why that pid isn't found. if "taks manager" doesn't show a pid, `processexplorer` by `sysinternals` will. sort using `tree view` -- whatever you're goal is, it might be a lot easier to implement using a an existing session addon

Comment: So you mean there is no way to do it? I have to kill the complete chrome process.

Comment: You might be able to enumerate processes, searching for a window title -- but what is your goal, why do you want to kill one window only? Why not just hit `x` on a window to close it? Then the rest are still open. This sounds like an XY question.