# Kill process after timeout when homonym processes are open - batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running many exe through multiple batches. Sometimes it happens that some exes got stuck so I chose to kill them after a timeout, like this:

```
CD mypath
start myexe.exe
timeout 60
TSKILL myexe
```

However, since all the exe have the same name, the batch does not close the exe it started but all of them. I also tried this:

```
cd mypath
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('start myexe^| find "ProcessId" ') do set MyPID=%%a
timeout 60
taskkill /PID %MyPID% /T
```

but the `timeout` starts just once the exe had finished.

How can I kill the process that the specific batch opened after a timeout?

Comment: You can go with powershell, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762982/powershell-get-process-id-of-called-application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got a link to a pure `powershell` solution in the comment to your quesiton, but if you want to retain the main `batch-file` format, you can incorporate some `powershell` into the batch file.

```
@echo off
pushd "mypath"
for /f %%i in ('powershell "(Start-Process myexe -passthru).ID"') do (
    timeout /t 60
    taskkill /PID %%i
)
popd
```

Note I replaced you `cd` command with `pushd` where later we have to `popd` to return to the directory before we used `pushd`. I is easier to push to and from directories without having to define the `cd` command each time. It is also not concerned about changing drives where `cd` requires the `/d` switch.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) to both run, and kill, your file too.

For example:

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=; " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe
 Process Call Create "T:\he\Absolute Path\To\My File\myexe.exe"
 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Id = "') Do @Set "PID=%%G"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 60 /NoBreak >NUL
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "ProcessId='%PID%'" Call^
 Terminate >NUL 2>&1
```

If you don't mind long lines, you dont need to split them for readability:

```sh
@For /F "Tokens=3 Delims=; " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Call Create "T:\he\Absolute Path\To\My File\myexe.exe" 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "Id = "') Do @Set "PID=%%G"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 60 /NoBreak >NUL
@%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "ProcessId='%PID%'" Call Terminate >NUL 2>&1
```